# Number of values in load file is not equal to number of columns

Tags: sql, load, informix

I delete some data by wrong and i want to retrieve them

I try to execute the following command :

```
LOAD FROM 'C:\db\rqrequesttrans.dat' delimiter '~' insert into rqrequesttrans
```

but i get the following error :

```
-- [Informix][Dynamic Server plus Universal Data Option][arch] SQL Error (-847) : Error in load file line 220.
-- [Informix][Dynamic Server plus Universal Data Option][arch] SQL Error (-846) : Number of values in load file is not equal to number of columns.
```

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Look at the 220th record in your load file and see what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a different number of data columns in the file than in the schema of the table for row 220.  Make sure row 220 has the right number of delimiters for your table.

I don't how many rows in your data table but check to make sure the file is complete.

Comment: the problem is because this char

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have no leading/trailing empty lines.
Informix complained about line 1 having the wrong number of columns and it was fixed by removing the last empty line.
Old thread, but I still found it and hopefully this helps the next person.